# How to make use of ion-tabs for routes in different modules in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I am just starting to use Ionic 4 with Angular and I am trying to add tabs to different routes. If I understand the official Ionic documentation, it turns out that if I want to have tabs, they should be placed in a parent component and each `tab` attribute should reference an actual child path.

However, I am looking for a different functionality. I want my tabs to be simply router links to different paths in my app that are not necessarily children of the container.

I decided to try adding a `routerLink` attribute to the `ion-tab-button` elements to see if I will get the desired result.

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button routerLinkActive="" [routerLink]="['/', 'content', 'dashboard']">
      <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/', 'content', 'explore']">
      <ion-label>Explore</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/', 'user']">
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

This seems to be working relatively fine, except for the fact that all tabs are now styled as if they were all active. How can I fix this and is there a "right" way of using tabs for routes within different modules?

Answer (score 3):

Tabs do not use routerLinks, but are tied to the router config itself.

As mentioned in [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs#router-integration), given a tab like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="schedule">
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Schedule</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

The `tabs-router.module.ts` would be expected to appear like so:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs-page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'schedule',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../schedule/schedule.module#ScheduleModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/app/tabs/schedule',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

It's best to look at the tabs starter for a better example.

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```